# Docker SDK for Python: fileobj

Tags: python, docker

Trying to build a docker image using the Docker SDK for Python (https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/images.html) I am wondering what is fileobj, and where is it described in the documentation

My purpose is to build a docker image based on a Dockerfile with a different name than the default file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a [standard Python file object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object); you might get one with the built-in [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function.  As is typical with Python you can also pass in a "file-like" object that supports a `read()` method; there are no checks that what you pass is *actually* a file.

Note that there's very little you can't do with the Docker CLI, and especially the image-building system is fairly fixed and self-contained.  On the flip side, the Docker API is complex and having access to it gives you unlimited root access to the host: mistakes can compromise your host.  For what you're describing the API is almost identical to the `docker build` command and I'd look again at if you can't use that directly; it doesn't seem likely you'll be able to get around any specific limitation you're encountering.

Comment: I will definitely consider using the CLI, maybe wrap it around simple functionalities using python - thanks!